# multiple dropdown search replacement string

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to create a search based on multiple dropdowns.

The snippet I use is the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function add_criteria (el) {
            search = document.getElementById('search_criteria');
            search.value = document.getElementById('type').value + " " + document.getElementById('color').value;}
    </script>

    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="search.html?submit=Go&_nkw">
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
    Type
    <select name='type' id='type' class='postform' onchange="add_criteria(this);">
      <option value='' selected='selected'>All</option>
      <option class="level-0" value="dog">Dog</option>
      <option class="level-0" value="cat">Cat</option>
    </select> 

    Color
    <select name='color' id='color' class='postform' onchange="add_criteria(this);">
      <option value='' selected='selected'>All</option>
      <option class="level-0" value="red">red</option>
      <option class="level-0" value="white">white</option>
      <option class="level-0" value="green">green</option>
    </select> 
       <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
      </div>
    </form>
```

The result however is not correct - what I would like to achieve is the result being displayed in this fashion:

```
    http://mystore.com/search.html?submit=Go&_nkw=medium+red
```

Does anybody have an idea on how I can get this replacement sting fixed and properly working?

Some advise would be highly appreciated - thank you very much!

Comment: `The result however is not correct`. Please show us your incorrect result or generated faulty URL. You mean to say encoded URL is incorrect?

Comment: Using the above snippet the search url comes out as: search.html?type=dog&color=green however I would like to achieve it looking like this: search.html?submit=Go&_nkw=dog+green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need just a simple trick. First of all get those `<select>` tags out of `<form>` tag, and make two fake `<input>` with name `submit` and `_nkw` (thats how [`<form>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp) element works):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function add_criteria (el) {
            search = document.getElementById('search_criteria');
            search.value = document.getElementById('type').value + " " + document.getElementById('color').value;}
    </script>

      <div>
        <select name='type' id='type' class='postform' onchange="add_criteria(this);">
            <option value='' selected='selected'>All</option>
            <option class="level-0" value="dog">Dog</option>
            <option class="level-0" value="cat">Cat</option>
        </select> 

        Color
        <select name='color' id='color' class='postform' onchange="add_criteria(this);">
            <option value='' selected='selected'>All</option>
            <option class="level-0" value="red">red</option>
            <option class="level-0" value="white">white</option>
            <option class="level-0" value="green">green</option>
        </select>
        </br>
        <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="search.html">
            <input name="submit" value="Go" style="visibility:hidden;"></label>
            <input id="search_criteria" name="_nkw" value="" style="visibility:hidden;"></label>
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
        </form>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is absolutely outstanding - thank you so much Ammar for your great help! I wish you have a good weekend ahead